# Force compile JasperReports jrxml files with ANT

Tags: ant, jasper-reports

When compiling Jasper jrxml reports using ANT ( this is relevant part of build.xml)

```
<taskdef name="jasperReportCompile" classname="net.sf.jasperreports.ant.JRAntCompileTask">
    <classpath refid="globalClasspath"/>
</taskdef>
```

Task compiles classes in the first run when the task runs the second time already compiled reports are omitted. I have updated Jasper reports to the new version so I would like to force recompilation of all reports.

Question: Is there a way to force JRAntCompileTask to compile already compiled reports. Maybe touch task or something similar?

Comment: Just delete the generated files? If you need to do this often, you can create a "clean" task in your Ant script.

Comment: Cleaning all classes + compilation lasts at least 15 min. Can I just clean.jasper files?

Comment: Sure, that's possible. I don't know your project setup, but you should be able to simply define a `fileset` in Ant that includes `**/*.jasper` and then delete it.